VS Code not working when opened
VS Code not working when opened
I installed it from the terminal and from the software store.
It stopped working after I updated to Ubuntu 24.04.
Google Chrome is also not working.

What exactly do you mean when you say VS Code is not working? Is there an error message which you can post us? Also how did you install VS Code or Chrome? APT or Snap?

Edit your question and add the information we ask for.
